# Ignore some members of a returned tuple in Julia

Tags: julia

Julia does not support multiple return, per se. However, Julia performs similar functionality by returning a tuple of values, which can then be assigned to a tuple of variables. For instance:

```
function mult_return()
    (3,2)
end
```

returns the tuple `(3,2)`. We can then assign these two return values to different variables, as follows:

`(a,b) = mult_return()` (or `a,b = mult_return()` because the parenthesis are not necessary.)

My question is this: **Is there a way to ignore one of the return values?** For example, in Matlab syntax, a user could write:

```
[~, b] = mult_return()
```

so that only the second value is assigned to a variable.

What is the proper way to approach this problem in Julia?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think you can do the same thing that is common in python, namely use underscores for skipped values. Example:

```
a, _ = mult_return()
```

It works multiple times as well

```
_, _ = mult_return()
```

Comment: Note that using `_` isn't skipping the result like `~` does in Matlab. It's just binding it to a variable that is typically  ignored by convention.

Comment: @MattB., you seem to be correct. In Julia this doesn't actually skip the assignment; in fact, it does define a variable named `_` that can be used later. But, if this a common convention, I am happy to go along with it.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than assigning the dummy variable _, you can just do

```
a, = mult_return()
```

in order to ignore the second return value, and similarly for larger tuples.

Comment: However, at least by my testing, this only lets you ignore later return values; you could not do `,a = mult_return()`, for example.